# paste range to new worksheet based on value change in loop column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm reasonably new to excel VBA and have hit a wall trying to develop a macro. I have output from an access database containing data in columns A to S. The output has a variable number of rows but always contains a header row. Column C has values which are common to several rows (i.e. C2:C7 might be 'Bananas', while C8:C9 might be 'Basket', and C10:C21 might be 'Bucket'), but the number of rows which have a common value in column C is dynamic. The values in column C are always contiguous.

I've been trying to create a macro which: identifies when the value in column C changes, pastes columns A to S for rows with the same value in column C (and the header row) to a new workbook saved with the column C value as the filename, deletes this range from the original workbook, and loops for the number of values in column C. My code seems to work if there are 3 values in column C; however, if there are more than this the code seems to ignore the criteria to look for a change in value in column C and creates new workbooks with ranges containing multiple values in column C.

I thought it may be due to the fact that the variables are not clearing for each iteration of the loop, but everything I've looked at on the web suggests this should not be an issue. The If statement seems to work when I've replaced the new workbook code with msgbox, but not with the workbook code. I believe it's a problem with the For loop but I'm not sure how to tackle that. I've googled and looked at countless SO pages but could not find an answer I could use. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
Sub number()

    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim cell, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("C2:C97")

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

        Set wbI = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsI = wbI.Worksheets("Worklist")
        Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

            With wbO
                 Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
                .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\svanwo0\Desktop\" & cell & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
                wsI.Range("A1:S1").Copy
                wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                wsI.Rows("2:" & cell.Row).Copy
                wsO.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
            End With
        Set wbI = Nothing
        Set wsI = Nothing
        Set wbO = Nothing
        Set wsO = Nothing

        Rows("2:" & cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)

        End If
    Next cell


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

vanw0001

Comment: This is one of those instances where going forward in a loop and deleting lines causes problems.  Since you are basically deleting the entire area of date i would wait till the end to delete. I would create a variable to hold the start row of the next block of data.  You have set the range it is going to iterate.  As you delete the data is shifted up but you are still going to the next physical row, it does not reset each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those instances where going forward in a loop and deleting lines causes problems.

You have set the range it is going to iterate. As you delete the data is shifted up but you are still going to the next physical row, it does not reset each time

Since you are basically deleting the entire area of date i would wait till the end to delete. I would create a variable to hold the start row of the next block of data.

```
Sub number()

    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim cell, rng As Range
    Dim stRw As Long
    Set rng = Range("C2:C97")
    stRw = 2
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

        Set wbI = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsI = wbI.Worksheets("Worklist")
        Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

            With wbO
                 Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
                .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\svanwo0\Desktop\" & cell & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
                wsI.Range("A1:S1").Copy
                wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                wsI.Rows(stRw & ":" & cell.Row).Copy
                wsO.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                .Close SaveChanges:=True
                stRw = cell.Row + 1
            End With
        Set wbI = Nothing
        Set wsI = Nothing
        Set wbO = Nothing
        Set wsO = Nothing



        End If
    Next cell
    Rows("2:97").EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)

End Sub
```